# Sonar Cobertura Plugin not finding coverage.xml file

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, cobertura

I have a multi-module maven project in `Jenkins` 1.545.I am using `Sonarqube` version 4.2.I have installed `cobertura` plugin version 1.6.1 and `java` plugin version 2.2.1 in `Sonarqube`.I have successfully generated `coverage.xml` file at location- `/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml` for each module using maven command- `"cobertura:cobertura -Dcobertura.report.format=xml"`
For sonar,i have set the maven build option as `sonar:sonar` with properties as below:

```
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
sonar.junit.reportsPath=target/site
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=cobertura
sonar.cobertura.reportPath=/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
```

I can see `coverage.xml` file when I browse the workspace of my project in `Jenkins` but the plugin keeps saying that it can't find it.I get the following message in console output of jenkins-

```
Execute Findbugs 2.0.3 done: 48446 ms
Sensor FindbugsSensor done: 48800 ms
Sensor CoberturaSensor...
Cobertura report not found at /target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
Sensor CoberturaSensor done: 4 ms
Sensor CpdSensor...
```

Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: what cobertura version used? as i know, sonar4.2 has some problem with high version cobertura. The sonar 4.7.3 may be work.

Comment: in my project, i use sonar4.2 and jacoco (same as cobertura).
get same error as your. then i update sonar to 3.7.4 , all work.

Comment: @CHmoonKa-I am using Cobertura version 1.6.1

Comment: It was not working with Sonar 3.7.4.Therefore i upgraded sonar to Sonarqube 4.2.

Comment: I am still facing the same issue.Can anyone help?

Comment: Finally my issue is resolved.While giving the relative path it should be "target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml" instead of "/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml" (relative path should not start with a slash).

Comment: But now i am facing another error "SquidIndex can't be null" while running Sonar Analysis.My jenkins build fail with the following error in console output:-                                         parsing {$MyPath}/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml 
[ERROR] SquidIndex can't be null 

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.3.1:sonar (default-cli) on project ing-top-level: Can not execute SonarQube analysis: SquidIndex can't be null                               Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue (**SonarQube 4.4.**, **Cobertura 1.6.2**, **Jenkins + maven + java8**) and I just finally figured out solution for the problem:

```
sonar.cobertura.reportPath=target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
```

***Notice the missing "/" from the beginning of the path!***

It actually tried to search from absolute root directory in my Linux server.